# Transfer fail, from Ledger-Nano-wallet to bisonapp.com

Tags: transactions, ether, transfer, ledger-nano-s

I have sent ETH from **Ledger Nano** to **BISONAp**p wallet. The transaction was confirmed. Unfortunately nothing arrived on the new wallet. Can anyone look inside the transaction history and tell why?

I am very grateful for any help!

Transaction Hash: https://etherscan.io/tx/0xde81510d6de9486393ac62cffd1124ce25c0f1c87837bb1e3d62a4d7a6153ebc

bisonapp Adress: https://etherscan.io/address/0x5a8871865f9569f7fc7560b170a3a031a0696b66

**At BISOApp there is an important note about what to consider when making crypto deposits:**

Please send only Ether (ETH) to this deposit address!

Only Ether can be sent to this deposit address via the Ethereum network.

No tokens from other blockchains, such as the Binance smartchain or Polygon, can be received. Sending digital assets from other blockchain networks will result in an irreversible loss.

Also, no tokens other than ETH can be received on this deposit address. Sending digital assets other than ETH will result in an irreversible loss. This applies in particular to ERC-20 tokens, which may be based on the Ethereum blockchain but are not identical to Ether (ETH) (e.g. UNI, LINK or ERC-20 tokens of the blockchain "Binance Smart Chain").

There will be no credit to your wallet in either case.

This deposit address only supports ETH!

Comment: The transfer has completed successfully, and you can see the funds appear in the address. You have to request the Biso app customer support to look into the issue, send them the transaction hash, if the address is correct they should credit your funds.

Comment: Ok, thank you Ismael